# Networking.service active failed

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I am using Kali Linux. My NetworkManager is enabled. But randomly my NetworkManager or networking.service goes down. Most of the time it's networking.service and my wifi is gone.
And Then I'm unable to turn on the networking.service
I think if I can configure the /etc/network/interfaces file properly then my issue might be fixed

```
    └─$ sudo systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-05-06 03:36:24 +06; 1min 28s ago
       Docs: man:interfaces(5)
    Process: 2693 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2693 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18384)
     Memory: 1.5M
        CPU: 2.141s
     CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service
             └─2724 /sbin/dhclient -4 -v -i -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases -I -df /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.wlan0.leases wlan0

May 06 03:36:12 pegasus ifup[2724]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
May 06 03:36:12 pegasus ifup[2724]: send_packet: Network is down
May 06 03:36:12 pegasus ifup[2724]: dhclient.c:2446: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
May 06 03:36:12 pegasus dhclient[2724]: send_packet: Network is down
May 06 03:36:12 pegasus dhclient[2724]: dhclient.c:2446: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
May 06 03:36:23 pegasus dhclient[2724]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
May 06 03:36:23 pegasus ifup[2724]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
May 06 03:36:23 pegasus ifup[2724]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
May 06 03:36:23 pegasus dhclient[2724]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
May 06 03:36:24 pegasus systemd[1]: Finished Raise network interfaces.
```

lspci

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev ff)
```

ip a

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:4a:0d:d8:42:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 70:66:55:98:e2:a1
```

ipnet, ifup, ifconfig

```
┌──(pegasus㉿pegasus)-[~]
└─$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up   
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation already in progress
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(pegasus㉿pegasus)-[~]
└─$ sudo ip link set wlan0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Operation already in progress
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
┌──(pegasus㉿pegasus)-[~]
└─$ sudo ifup wlan0          
ifup: interface wlan0 already configured
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:5e:45:d4:9e:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 580 (580.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 580 (580.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.168.176  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.168.255
        inet6 fe80::5dcf:878c:b723:4fef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:b0:8b:06:a0:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30207  bytes 30987462 (29.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23574  bytes 4358491 (4.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `lspci -kn  -d ::0280`?

Comment: Nothing comes. And rn the netwoking.service fails to turn on. I guess that's the main issue. When I put auto wlan0. in /etc/network/interfaces then the networking.service couldn’t turn on.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: It seems that you do not have the wifi card drivers installed. You have to find the exact model of your card (use `lspci` or `inxi -N`), then report it to try to guide you on that.

Comment: Check the post.

Comment: [This post](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?51043-Realtek-RTL-8822CE-DRIVER&p=102065#post102065) reported that the driver for 8821ce worked for the 8822ce (yours). You can give it a try (follow manual install from [here](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce).

Comment: It's not just a simple driver issue. The rtw8822ce has a problem with linux for a long time now. Buy somehow the conf files change can fix this issue. But I'm not sure about the exact change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136089/discussion-between-brahim-gaabab-and-zeshan-ahmed-nobin).